# Rails 3: How do I mix form params and URL params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a legacy app and am trying to upgrade it to Rails 3. Currently when I do a search I get the URL: `http://localhost:3000/search/external_search/?keyword=argentina`. However, when I try to filter out the results, I get `http://localhost:3000/search/external_search/?order=Name:ASC`, without the keyword parameter in the URL. Since there wasn't a keyword params, the filter wouldn't work. This was messing up my filter, so I decided to add a hidden field tag

`<%= hidden_field_tag 'keyword', @search.text %>`

which makes it work, but the URL didn't change. I want it to look like:

`http://localhost:3000/search/external_search/?keyword=argentina&order=Name:ASC`

Where exactly would I accomplish this? In the controller or the form?

Comment: The `params` hash in ROR doesn't care where the variables come from.  What's in your controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the parameters of the submited form in the URL, you must use `GET` method instead of `POST`.

Add the option `:method => :get` to the `form_for` or `form_tag` enclosing the `<%= hidden_field_tag 'keyword', @search.text %>`